# Using dotjs in express

Tags: node.js, express, dotjs

I want to use [dotjs](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html) to replace Jade for Express

I changed

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

to

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');    
app.engine('html', dot.compile);
```

but it isn't loading for a long time and I'm not getting a response;

what's wrong with it ?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://github.com/defunkt/dotjs)? How are you going to use it in Express? It's a Chrome extension...

Comment: He means http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html

Comment: take at look at the markdown example, you need to compose your middleware like that https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/markdown/index.js

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use express-dot:

```
npm install express-dot
```

and in your app.js:

```
var doT = require('express-dot');
// (optional) set globals any thing you want to be exposed by this in {{= }} and in def {{# }}
doT.setGlobals({ ... });
app.set('view engine', 'dot' );
app.engine('dot', doT.__express );
```

Of cause, it is suggested that compose your own as generalhenry said.
Becase if you do that , you will understand express and dot better.
express-dot do not support pre-compile, so I have a simple [pre-compile example](https://github.com/albertshaw/Snippets/blob/master/express-dot.js) in my Github repo.
Good luck.